# Reading txt file using stored procedure and manipulation with the same

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I would like to speed up a process of reading data from txt file. txt file looks as following:

```
"NameA";"407;410;500"  
"NameB";"407;510"
"NameC";"407;420;500;600"
```

and I would like to have it as :

```
"NameA";"407"
"NameA";"410"
"NameA";"500"
"NameB";"407"
"NameB";"510"
"NameC";"407"
"NameC";"420"
"NameC";"500"
"NameC";"600"
```

Any thoughts on performing the task with SQL stored procedure?

Thanks

Comment: It's store**D** procedures (with a **d** at the end) - as in **stored** in your database server - they have nothing to do with a "store" ..... also: **what database** and what version thereof are we talking about here?? **SQL** = structured query language - that's just the language used to query the database - but a lot of database systems use SQL as their query language - doesn't help us knowing what you're using....

Answer (score 0):

Any thoughts? Yes... don't do it!

PL/SQL is only good for handling "database" objects - tables, rows, columns etc. Don't try to get it to do something it's not suited for - it will only lead to frustration and a bad solution.

Instead, use a shell script/command to massage your input file into a form directly and conveniently useable by your database.

I would suggest using `sed` or `awk`.